# Make two vector points move together (Sketch or Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, sketch-app

I'm trying to speed up my workflow by making vector points move in the opposite direction simultaneously when I have two highlighted. For instance, below I highlight the top and bottom of the arrow so they will move at the same time, except **I want the bottom point to come up when I'm moving the top point down**. Right now, they just move up together or down together. So if point 1 is at Y:20 and point 2 is at Y:10, I want them both to go to Y:15 if I move point 1 down 5 pixels.

[image]

### What it currently does

[image]

### What I want it to do

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If the move is symmetrical.

1. Select both points
2. Menu > Object > Transform > Scale
3. Check the
   preview box in the bottom of the new window and adjust from there.

You could also use guidelines, the grid Ctl or Cmd (') or simply using the arrow keys.

Comment: Is it possible to scale just two points? Even if I select two points it scales the whole object.

Comment: yes, press (A) on the keyboard, then you can individually select two points. You can either click and drag the two points or if there are any other elements in the way you can click the first point and then press+hold (Shift) then click the second point. Shift allows you to either continuously "gather or add points/objects" to you current selected items. Shift clicking also also allows you to remove points/objects from your current selection if you accidentally selected an addition thing or if you just don't want to interact with a specific element.

Comment: btw (A) is the direct selection tool. It is the white mouse pointer in the tool bar, which is adjacent to the black arrow which for selecting whole shapes etc. Hope this helps